# jQuery 'each' loop with JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, each

I'm trying to use jQuery's `each` loop to go through this JSON and add it to a `div` named `#contentHere`. The JSON is as follows:

```
{ "justIn": [
  { "textId": "123", "text": "Hello", "textType": "Greeting" },
  { "textId": "514", "text":"What's up?", "textType": "Question" },
  { "textId": "122", "text":"Come over here", "textType": "Order" }
  ],
 "recent": [
  { "textId": "1255", "text": "Hello", "textType": "Greeting" },
  { "textId": "6564", "text":"What's up?", "textType": "Question" },
  { "textId": "0192", "text":"Come over here", "textType": "Order" }
  ],
 "old": [
  { "textId": "5213", "text": "Hello", "textType": "Greeting" },
  { "textId": "9758", "text":"What's up?", "textType": "Question" },
  { "textId": "7655", "text":"Come over here", "textType": "Order" }
 ]
}
```

I'm getting this JSON through use of this code:

```
$.get("data.php", function(data){

})
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Do you have a template for the html you want to produce?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try (untested):

```
$.getJSON("data.php", function(data){
    $.each(data.justIn, function() {
        $.each(this, function(k, v) {
            alert(k + ' ' + v);
        });
    });
    $.each(data.recent, function() {
        $.each(this, function(k, v) {
            alert(k + ' ' + v);
        });
    });
    $.each(data.old, function() {
        $.each(this, function(k, v) {
            alert(k + ' ' + v);
        });
    });    
});
```

I figured, three separate loops since you'll probably want to treat each dataset differently (justIn, recent, old). If not, you can do:

```
$.getJSON("data.php", function(data){
    $.each(data, function(k, v) {
        alert(k + ' ' + v);
        $.each(v, function(k1, v1) {
            alert(k1 + ' ' + v1);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @downvoter - What warranted a downvote? Kindly explain, I would like to know what is amiss.

Comment: Clear, concise and elegant !

Comment: Hi @karim79 How to show a single/specific item array above? is 'Alert(k1 + ' ' + v1[0].TextType)?. I was try but, I got 'not defined' error message

Answer (score 9):

### Brief code but full-featured

The following is a hybrid jQuery solution that formats each data "record" into an HTML element and uses the data's properties as HTML attribute values.

The jquery `each` runs the inner loop; I needed the regular JavaScript `for` on the outer loop to be able to grab the property name (instead of value) for display as the heading. According to taste it can be modified for slightly different behaviour.

This is **only 5 main lines of code** but wrapped onto multiple lines for display:

```
$.get("data.php", function(data){

    for (var propTitle in data) {

        $('<div></div>') 
            .addClass('heading')
            .insertBefore('#contentHere')
            .text(propTitle);

            $(data[propTitle]).each(function(iRec, oRec) {

                $('<div></div>')
                    .addClass(oRec.textType)
                    .attr('id', 'T'+oRec.textId)
                    .insertBefore('#contentHere')
                    .text(oRec.text);
            });
    }

});
```

Produces the output

*(Note: I modified the JSON data text values by prepending a number to ensure I was displaying the proper records in the proper sequence - while "debugging")*

```
<div class="heading">
    justIn
</div>
<div id="T123" class="Greeting">
    1Hello
</div>
<div id="T514" class="Question">
    1What's up?
</div>
<div id="T122" class="Order">
    1Come over here
</div>
<div class="heading">
    recent
</div>
<div id="T1255" class="Greeting">
    2Hello
</div>
<div id="T6564" class="Question">
    2What's up?
</div>
<div id="T0192" class="Order">
    2Come over here
</div>
<div class="heading">
    old
</div>
<div id="T5213" class="Greeting">
    3Hello
</div>
<div id="T9758" class="Question">
    3What's up?
</div>
<div id="T7655" class="Order">
    3Come over here
</div>
<div id="contentHere"></div>
```

Apply a style sheet

```
<style>
.heading { font-size: 24px; text-decoration:underline }
.Greeting { color: green; }
.Question { color: blue; }
.Order { color: red; }
</style>
```

to get a "beautiful" looking set of data

[image]

**More Info**
The JSON data was used in the following way:

for each category (key name the array is held under):

- the key name is used as the section heading (e.g. **justIn**)

for each object held inside an array:

- 'text' becomes the content of a div
- 'textType' becomes the class of the div (hooked into a style sheet)
- 'textId' becomes the id of the div
- e.g. **<div id="T122" class="Order">Come over here</div>**

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
$.get("data.php", function(data){
    var expected = ['justIn', 'recent', 'old'];
    var outString = '';
    $.each(expected, function(i, val){
        var contentArray = data[val];
        outString += '<ul><li><b>' + val + '</b>: ';
        $.each(contentArray, function(i1, val2){
            var textID = val2.textId;
            var text = val2.text;
            var textType = val2.textType;
            outString += '<br />('+textID+') '+'<i>'+text+'</i> '+textType;
        });
        outString += '</li></ul>';
    });
    $('#contentHere').append(outString);
}, 'json');
```

This produces this output:

```
<div id="contentHere"><ul>
<li><b>justIn</b>:
<br />
(123) <i>Hello</i> Greeting<br>
(514) <i>What's up?</i> Question<br>
(122) <i>Come over here</i> Order</li>
</ul><ul>
<li><b>recent</b>:
<br />
(1255) <i>Hello</i> Greeting<br>
(6564) <i>What's up?</i> Question<br>
(0192) <i>Come over here</i> Order</li>
</ul><ul>
<li><b>old</b>:
<br />
(5213) <i>Hello</i> Greeting<br>
(9758) <i>What's up?</i> Question<br>
(7655) <i>Come over here</i> Order</li>
</ul></div>
```

And looks like this:

- **justIn**:
  (123) *Hello* Greeting
  (514) *What's up?* Question
  (122) *Come over here* Order

- **recent**:
  (1255) *Hello* Greeting
  (6564) *What's up?* Question
  (0192) *Come over here* Order

- **old**:
  (5213) *Hello* Greeting
  (9758) *What's up?* Question
  (7655) *Come over here* Order

Also, remember to set the `contentType` as `'json'`

Answer (score 0):

My solutions in one of my own sites, with a table:

```
$.getJSON("sections/view_numbers_update.php", function(data) {
 $.each(data, function(index, objNumber) {
  $('#tr_' + objNumber.intID).find("td").eq(3).html(objNumber.datLastCalled);
  $('#tr_' + objNumber.intID).find("td").eq(4).html(objNumber.strStatus);
  $('#tr_' + objNumber.intID).find("td").eq(5).html(objNumber.intDuration);
  $('#tr_' + objNumber.intID).find("td").eq(6).html(objNumber.blnWasHuman);
 });
});
```

sections/view_numbers_update.php Returns something like:

```
[{"intID":"19","datLastCalled":"Thu, 10 Jan 13 08:52:20 +0000","strStatus":"Completed","intDuration":"0:04 secs","blnWasHuman":"Yes","datModified":1357807940},
{"intID":"22","datLastCalled":"Thu, 10 Jan 13 08:54:43 +0000","strStatus":"Completed","intDuration":"0:00 secs","blnWasHuman":"Yes","datModified":1357808079}]
```

HTML table:

```
<table id="table_numbers">
 <tr>
  <th>[...]</th>
  <th>[...]</th>
  <th>[...]</th>
  <th>Last Call</th>
  <th>Status</th>
  <th>Duration</th>
  <th>Human?</th>
  <th>[...]</th>
 </tr>
 <tr id="tr_123456">
  [...]
 </tr>
</table>
```

This essentially gives every row a unique id preceding with 'tr_' to allow for other numbered element ids, at server script time. The jQuery script then just gets this TR_[id] element, and fills the correct indexed cell with the json return.

The advantage is you could get the complete array from the DB, and either foreach($array as $record) to create the table html, OR (if there is an update request) you can die(json_encode($array)) before displaying the table, all in the same page, but same display code.