# Parsing Datasnap result using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, delphi, datasnap

I'm trying to return a list of data from Delphi to a  listbox and I think I'm failing to grasp a fundamental of how it all fits together.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861032/loop-and-get-key-value-pair-for-json-array-using-jquery) has got me a working example using a locally defined dataset.

The issue I now have is the structure of the JSON object returned by my Delphi code.

In the above answer there is only 1 "tier" of data in the object:

```
resultJSON = '{"1":"Firm 1","2":"Firm 2","3":"Firm 3"}';
```

However my Delphi Code seems to add an tier.
The query is as follows:

```
function TServerMethods1.GetFirms(jobnumb: string): TJSONObject;
var
   jso: TJSONObject;
begin
   jso := TJSONObject.Create();
   GetJobFirmList(jobnumb);
   with SQLQuery1 do
      while not Eof do
      begin
         jso.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create(FieldByName('firmref').AsString,
                                  FieldByName('firmnaem').AsString));
         Next;
      end;
   Result := jso;
end;
```

This returns the following result format:

```
 {"result":[{"1":"Firm 1","2":"Firm 2","3":"Firm 3"}]}
```

I either need to reduce the code outside the square braces, or understand how to iterate the levels better.

This [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030321/jquery-each-loop-with-json-array) shows how to parse two tiers in a similar structure but the best I can come up with integrating the two is the following which fails:

```
function getJobFirms()
{
  var sel = $("#FirmList");
  sel.empty();
  var resultJSON = '{"result":[{"1":"Firm 1","2":"Firm 2","3":"Firm 3"}]}';
  var result = $.parseJSON(resultJSON);
  $.each(result, function() {      
    $.each(result.result, function(k,v) {
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.value = k;
      opt.text = v;
      sel.append(opt);
     });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, it appears that you are incorrectly iterating your JSON structure. Namely, `result.result` is an array, so you can try something like this:

```
function getJobFirms()
{
    var sel = $("#FirmList");
    sel.empty();
    var resultJSON = '{"result":[{"1":"Firm 1","2":"Firm 2","3":"Firm 3"}]}';
    var result = $.parseJSON(resultJSON);
    $.each(result.result, function(i, resultItem) {
        $.each(resultItem, function(k, v) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = k;
            opt.text = v;
            sel.append(opt);
        });
    });
}
```

Also, if you have only one element in `result.result` array, you can reduce code even more:

```
function getJobFirms()
{
    var sel = $("#FirmList");
    sel.empty();
    var resultJSON = '{"result":[{"1":"Firm 1","2":"Firm 2","3":"Firm 3"}]}';
    var result = $.parseJSON(resultJSON);
    $.each(result.result[0], function(k, v) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = k;
        opt.text = v;
        sel.append(opt);
    });
}
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't like the parseJSON - adding an extra $.each loop gets me where I need to be.  Just need to understand why Delphi/Datasnap returns in this format...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. This above should work in your situation, especially when first `for` loop in your example doesn't seem to do anything. Also, you could reduce code even more, if you iterate (only inner loop) trough `result.result[0]`, if that works for you.

Comment: Edited for another example.

Comment: Thanks for the examples @miloss.  They both work on the JSON set as returned from the server - however there is another function (which comes with the specific Delphi examples and is used to get the JSON from the server) - that must mangle the JSON so that ParseJSON doesn't like it.