# JSon parse return error on my code

Tags: php, json

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var obj = "";
var param = [{ "name": "id", value: 9}];   
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '2.php',
  data: param,
  success: function(dataFetch) {
var obj = JSON.parse(dataFetch);
alert(obj[0].name);
 },
  dataType: 'json',
  async:false
});
});
</script>
```

above is my code. The return result of 2.php is

```
{"name":"Halford Tee","type":"client","mobile":"1234567","location":"","description":""}
```

It give me an **`error`**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

When I remove this part

```
var obj = JSON.parse(dataFetch);
alert(obj[0].name);
```

The error is gone. Is there anything wrong with my code?

---

**After looking at valuable guide from fellow programer**

My 2.php returns

```
{"name":"David Tan","type":"leads","mobile":"91234567","location":"","description":""}
```

I tried the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var obj = "";
var param = [{ "name": "eventId", value: 9}];   
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '2.php',
  data: param,
  success: function(dataFetch) {
alert(dataFetch[0].name);
 },
  dataType: 'json',
  async:false
});
});
```

It give me an error

```
cannot read property 'name' of undefined.
```

Comment: `dataType: 'json'` will make jQuery parse the response automatically. What happens if you only use `alert(dataFetch[0].name);`?

Comment: use console.log(dataFetch); and see what you got.

Comment: The json string returned by 2.php doesn't have an array. Try `alert(dataFetch.name);`

Comment: Object {name: "David Tan", type: "leads", mobile: "91234567", location: "", description: ""}

Comment: use dataFetch.name because it is an object.

Comment: Manage to fetch using dataFetch.name instead of dataFetch[0].name Thanks! But I got another question, what if my return json is more than 2 rows, because for this case I only got 1 row.

Comment: in that case loop through your data using $.each .read about it.

Comment: see this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030321/jquery-each-loop-with-json-array

Comment: @SuchitKumar Thanks sir for the valuable knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax then you don't need to use `JSON.parse.` your data will automatically be parsed in `json format`.so you can directly use it.

```
 use : `alert(dataFetch.name);`// you do not have any array so directly use it.your data is an object not array of object.
```

**note:** i think you should use  `async:false` only when your calling has to complete before the next statement in your function can be called.

Comment: I updated my question and it seems got issue still. yes it has to be complete before the next statement can be called.

Answer (score 0):

After: var obj = JSON.parse(dataFetch);

```
alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

it might help you to rectify your problem.

Comment: After doing alert you will find keys and values related to that json you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

(This answer is based on your comment that there might be more than one row.)

I think this is one of those ***always-1*** vs ***0-or-more*** vs ***1-or-more*** problems.

You have to decide, ***exactly*** what does 2.php return?

1. Always a single row?  `{"name":"David Tan",...}`
2. Always an array of zero-or-more rows? `[{"name":"David Tan",...}, {"name":"Clark Kent",...},...]`
3. Or simply one-or-more rows, but not bracketed as an array?  `{"name":"David Tan",...}{"name":"Clark Kent",...}`

In case (1), `dataFetch.name` is "David Tan".

In case (2), `dataFetch[0].name` is "David Tan".

In case (3), your output is not valid JSON. If you have the ability to change the PHP script, then change the output to Case (2) format <*<**GOOD SOLUTION***. If you must deal with someone else's PHP script, then you need to change your ajax call to `dataType: "text"`, then clean it up to make it valid JSON, then parse the JSON client-side. You ***do not*** want to omit dataType and have jQuery default to "Intelligent Guess", because results will vary depending on how many rows there are in the output.